# Burnside groups : a few questions

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, group-actions, group-presentation, automorphism-group

Let $G=B(n,e)=F_n/\langle\langle F_n^e\rangle\rangle$ be the Burnside group on $n$ generators with exponent $e$, i.e. the quotient of the free group on $n$ generators $F_n$ by the normal subgroup generated by the set of $e$-th powers $ F_n^e=\{x^e\mid x\in F_n\}$.

It is a theorem that for odd $e>664$, $G$ is infinite.
Here are my questions :

1. Does $G$ have a trivial center?
2. Do the automorphisms of $G$ act transitively on $G^*=G-\{1\}$? What about the inner automorphisms?
3. If the action is indeed transitive, how transitive is it? I.e. are there simple criteria for determining whether a $k$-tuple $(g_1,\dots,g_k)$ can be transformed to $(h_1,\dots,h_k)$ via some automorphism?
4. Suppose $e$ is prime and $g,h$ don't commute: is the subgroup $\langle g,h\rangle$ isomorphic to $B(2,e)$?

References welcome.

Comment: The answer to Question 2 is no for $e >2$ and $n>1$, because $[G,G]$ is a proper nontrivial characteristic subgroup.

Comment: @DerekHolt Makes sense. Is the quotient isomorphic to $(Z/eZ)^d$?

Comment: Yes that's right.

Comment: @DerekHolt Do you know whether (say, for prime $e$) automorphisms of the abelianization lift to automorphisms of $B(n,e)$?

Comment: Hmm. I guess you can find lifts of a generating set (transvections and dilations) of $GL_d(Z/eZ)$.

Comment: I think the answer to that is yes. (for prime $e$) The automorphism group of the free group $F_n$  induces ${\rm GL}_n({\mathbb Z})$ on the abelianization $F_n/F_n'$, and so it  induces ${\rm SL}^\pm_n(e)$ on $G/G'$. By raising one of the generators to powers you get the whole of ${\rm GL}_n(e)$.